# android firebase unable to add second child

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

My code:

```
btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            NewQuestionData nqd = new NewQuestionData(question.getText().toString(),keywords.getText().toString(),description.getText().toString());
            databaseReference.child(firebaseUser.getUid()).child("question"+Math.random()).setValue(nqd);
        }
    });
```

Every time I insert value into the database, it fails.

Problem is here:

`child("question"+Math.random())`

I want to add unique ID with every question.

Following works fine:

`child("question")`

Please share your valuable suggessions, How to insert unique child for every new question inserted into the Firebase Database.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
String key = databaseReference.child(firebaseUser.getUid()).child("question").push().getKey();
databaseReference.child(firebaseUser.getUid()).child("question").child(key).setValue(nqd);

// key is unique every time you add your new question.
```

For more info you can visit https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write

OR

you can use `System.currentTimeMillis()`
It will give timestamp in long and is always unique.

```
databaseReference.child(firebaseUser.getUid()).child("question"+System.currentTimeMillis()).setValue(nqd);
```

Comment: This works only if the client code keeps a track of the keys which in his case he might have to eventually because he is using a random generator. But he might not be interested to fetch a particular child (Depends on his use case). All he wants now is to insert the child with a unique key.

Comment: Thats what the above code will do. It will insert the child with unique key.

Comment: Agreed. The autigenerated key would be anyways unique. So it would serve the purpose.

Comment: also we can use `System.currentTimeMillis()`. Check the updated answer.

Comment: Yup. As long as the combined key length does not exceed Firebase key legth threshold

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the random generator function `Math.random()` generates values between 0 and 1 which would have the decimal point - `.`
Now this decimal when added to a string would look something like `question0.0001`

If you check the Firebase documentation, you would see that `.` is a forbidden character in a key. So this would be your problem. If you at all want to generate a random value, use something which will generate random values from 0 to INTEGER_MAX.

Answer (score 0):

To insert a child with a unique key without having to worry about it, call Firebase's `push()` method. See the [Firebase documentation on appending data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#append_to_a_list_of_data).

Your code could be:

```
databaseReference
    .child(firebaseUser.getUid())
    .push()
    .setValue(nqd);
```

This will generate a unique key of the format specified in this blog post: [The 2^120 Ways to Ensure Unique Identifiers](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/02/the-2120-ways-to-ensure-unique_68.html).

If you still want to use the `question` prefix, you can use `push()` as a separate call (it's a client-side call that doesn't connect to the Database):

```
String key = databaseReference.push().getKey(); // gets a unique ID
databaseReference
    .child(firebaseUser.getUid())
    .child("question"+key)
    .setValue(nqd);
```